# Displaying price limit above price slider scale

Tags: e-commerce, filter, sliders

I'm working on adding a price slider to an existing price filter on an e-commerce shop that uses price buckets (predefined price ranges).

If the user selects any of the price buckets, the slider above would update as well (but we won't update it *vice versa*, for obvious reasons). However, for the last option, "above 50", I can't figure out a way to display this on the slider as it would be infinite. Any ideas on how the slider would display the last option?

P.S. We ruled out changing the last option to another price bucket as we can't dynamically define the buckets based on the most expensive item in the shop.

[image]

Comment: How does a user use the slider to select above 150?

Comment: I assume it's not just a visual indicator: The user can filter using the slider, right?

Comment: @plainclothes yes, this is an interactive control

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use the label MAX or MAXIMUM :
[image]

Comment: +1 > the right end should represent the max, just as the left end should represent 0 or your minimum.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the sliders (knobs) to show the direction of the range, and you can remove one of the sliders if the range isn't bound:

[image: Example of bound and unbound range]

Comment: How would a user know to remove the indicator?

Comment: @plainclothes Click one of the other three ranges. They'd know about these links because one of them made the upper-limit slider disappear. A usability test would show how confusing that is, and thus whether it's a good design idea.

Comment: So you would disallow activation of the upper limit without first activating one of the fixed groups? IOW, the slider wouldn't be fully operational without using another control.

Comment: @plainclothes I guess you have a hypothesis about how this would perform in a usability test where people want to switch from an "unbounded" range to a bounded range. I don't know what the customers or users are expected to do, so I have no hypothesis.

Comment: Fair enough. My hypothesis (based on previous ecomm tests) is that when provided with two ways to filter (fixed ranges or a slider) users won't consistently choose one over the other. Limiting the features of the slider option (which has gained in popularity) seems like an unnecessary constraint.

Comment: @plainclothes Yes. It's an interesting design problem. for the infinite side of the range, I thought about changing the shape of the slider instead of removing it. Can you think of other ways to show "150 and up"…? There must be more ways.

Comment: @DesignerAnalyst solved it as I have in the past: make the edges represent the extremes.

Comment: @plainclothes I wonder whether some users might not recognize that, because the scale of most of the line is from 0 to 50, which implies the rest of the slider range perhaps extends to 200. Again, it would be interesting to test with the intended customers or users.

Comment: Labels to the rescue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32896/discussion-between-jeromer-and-plainclothes).

Answer (score 0):

There is very elegant solution to this problem:

Before displaying the ranges and slider you ask the system: *What is the smallest and largest price?*

Then ask the system to **make evenly distributed buckets between min and max price.**

User experience is about creating usable interfaces. MAX doesn't tell user what is maximum value. Same for minimal value. So you should display them.

Also, predefined price rages can have badly grouped number of items.

Example: from $10-50 there are 500 items, but from $100-150 there are only 3.

That is bad UX. Let the system create more meaningful price ranges for the users.